# Host NetBean html5 app on iis

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, netbeans

I download NetBean IDE and did the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html)

but now I want to **host the site on my local IIS** and I can't find in Google way of doing it.
Someone know if it possible? and if yes how?

**Note:** I am coming from the world of ASP.NET and I used to host my web apps on IIS...

Answer (score 1):

If you open Project Properties dialog (right click on the project and select `Project Properties`) and switch to `Run` category, there is  a field called `Web Server`. NetBeans uses for HTML5 projects Embedded server by default but if you place your project to some `"DocumentRoot"` (sorry, don't know the terminology of IIS), then you can switch to `External` server in the the dialog and provide URL at which your project is available.

Note that NetBeans won't control your IIS, you simply provides URL which should be opened in browser once you run the project (so the server must be already running and your project must be in the document root)